Genymotion - Cannot install on Xubuntu
I understand this is partially a Ubuntu matter but since it's more to mobile development because the question is about Genymotion and if there's any answer for it, it supposed to be here, so I ask the question here.
On my Xubuntu (XFCE version of Ubuntu), I've downloaded the Genymotion from here and tried to install it following the given instructions, before getting this error

Removing old installation ............................ OK
Extracting files ..................................... tar (grandchild): bzip2: Cannot exec: No such file or directory tar
(grandchild): Error is not recoverable: exiting now tar: Child died
with signal 13 tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now Aborting.


The answer is VirtualBox need to be installed first.
I've no idea why I couldn't find anything answering my question anywhere. And why Genymotion itself mention nothing about it.
